# How to automate webpage span control like slider values by using like driver. findElement_by_xpath () , Ubuntu Linux and chromium Autotest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am very much new to this webUI automaton. It would be great if you could suggest some solution to automate the following web link's span controls:

1. the  below Head-Coupled 3D Demo  file Browsing using the below link 
   "http://sheepeuh.com/particles/"
2. I have to automate the  changes which are the settings over on the browser top right corner. For example:  I have change  'Alpha' span slider     value like 20 %. How this can be automate using selenium-python  like driver `findElement_by_xpath()`?

HTML code:

```
<li class="cr number has-slider"><div><span class="property-name">Alpha</span><div class="c"><div><input type="text"></div><div class="slider"><div class="slider-fg" style="width: 100%;"></div></div></div></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the position of the `li` element is not quite reliable and readable.

Instead *rely on the property label*:

```
alpha_val_xpath = '//span[. = "Alpha"]/following-sibling::div//input'

alpha_val_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(alpha_val_xpath)
alpha_val_elem.clear()
alpha_val_elem.send_keys('5' + Keys.ENTER)
```

Then, you can make a nice reusable function that would enter any property value you need:

```
def set_property(driver, name, value):
    xpath = '//span[. = "%s"]/following-sibling::div//input' % name

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys(str(value) + Keys.ENTER)
```

Example usages:

```
set_property(driver, 'Alpha', 5) 
set_property(driver, 'Width division', 15)
```

Results into (I've highlighted the properties set by the script):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Alecxe for you valuable suggestion.  I will try this.

Comment: Hi Alexe, You suggested solution is worked very well for several website. However, Same logic  is not working for http://codepen.io/Francext/full/ogAqH  .   It seems to both the web page (this and above) are pretty same. I am unable to find root cause of why same logic is not working here. If possible, could you please suggest any  solution.  I highly appreciate your valuable time and suggestion.

Comment: @UstchromiumDatta please make a separate question and provide the details. Throw the link here also for me please. This way there would be more potential people looking and trying to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For example, in order to change the Alpha to 5 you should use:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = Firefox()
driver.get('http://sheepeuh.com/particles/')
alpha_val_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[12]/div/div/div[1]/input'

alpha_val_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(alpha_val_xpath)
alpha_val_elem.clear()
alpha_val_elem.send_keys('5' + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you valuable suggestion.  I will try this.